# One fact table per event?

Tags: database-design, database-schema, data-warehouse

I work for a Police Force that is considering developing a Data Warehouse to manage information.  It holds information in about ten databases:

1. Crime database
2. Intelligence database
3. Collision database
4. Domestic violence database

These events e.g. crimes,intelligence etc have nothing to do with each other.  I am planning to create copy databases for each of these.  Once I have created the copy databases I will attempt to create a star schema/snowflake schema.

Would I have one fact table per event e.g. crime fact table, intelligence fact table etc or would I have one dimension per event? Different information is held about each event.  For example, with crimes you have offenders and victims and collisions have persons.

All the examples I find online and in my book seem to have one fact table except this one [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=multiple%20fact%20tables%20in%20star%20schema&biw=1366&bih=631&tbm=isch&imgil=yya8oka0zRf9JM%253A%253BfbILCrg1A6LMLM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fblog-mstechnology.blogspot.com%25252F2010%25252F06%25252Fbi-dimensional-model-fact-constellation.html&source=iu&pf=m&fir=yya8oka0zRf9JM%253A%252CfbILCrg1A6LMLM%252C_&usg=__JDQwR0N0E1PH9Rfdcg1OuzG97Qg%3D&ved=0CD4Qyjc&ei=07NLVJi9GYbV7Aad5oCgCQ#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=yya8oka0zRf9JM%253A%3BfbILCrg1A6LMLM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252F1.bp.blogspot.com%252F_9rNebBXDgwA%252FTBvK0smJ8GI%252FAAAAAAAAAtQ%252FKgPZukqAX0U%252Fs1600%252Fgalaxy.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fblog-mstechnology.blogspot.com%252F2010%252F06%252Fbi-dimensional-model-fact-constellation.html%3B666%3B383).

Answer (score 1):

The decision on the number of fact tables is driven by considerations such as:

- Do the entities have consistent dimensions that are "conformable"?
- Are the facts similar for the different entities?
- Will the queries generally be entity-specific or across entity?

I might imagine a system where you have a summary reporting system with a single fact table and dimensions such as:

- time
- type of incident
- location of incident

And facts such as:

- number of victims
- number of perpetrators
- time to respond

(or whatever).

You can then have a more detailed database that stores the detailed level information for the different crimes.  For instance, the specifics for a domestic violence incident will be different from one for collisions.  You don't have to use a star-schema design.  I would, in fact, recommend entity-relation structure to store the detailed data.

Comment: Thanks.  Would the more: "detailled database" be the copy database or another database optimized for searching?

Comment: @w0051977 . . . I don't know what the source data looks like or what the design requirements are for the data warehouse.  In my experience, data from operational systems often needs to be somewhat cleaned/reformatted for data warehouses.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can you support you statement "I would, in fact, recommend entity-relation structure to store the detailed data" with facts or considerations?

Comment: @Skoffer . . . That statement is based on the observation that the dimensions for the different types of events might be quite different.  If there is little overlaps among the dimensions, then an entity-relationship structure seems more appropriate.